# Is there a way to define the [ ] operator for an instance of class?

Tags: python, object, operators

I want to define  class to represent a matrix

```
class matrix:
    def __init__(self, mat):
        self.mat = mat
        self.dim = len(mat)

    @classmethod
    def withDim(matrix, dimension):
        mat = [ [0]*dimension for i in range(dimension)]
        return matrix(mat)
```

where `mat` is a list of lists, so to represent the matrix

```
A = | a b |
    | c d |
```

I can write the following

```
A = matrix( [ [a, b], [c, d] ])
```

I've also started to define some operators, like

```
def __add__(self, other):
    n = self.dim
    result = self.withDim(n)
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            result.mat[i][j] = self.mat[i][j] + other.mat[i][j]
    return result
```

Now if I want to access element `i, j` in matrix `A` I have to do

```
A.mat[i][j]
```

The question is: can I define the operator `[ ]` in order to do

```
A[i][j]
```

just like I defined `__add__`?

Comment: In `__add__` there it should be `self.withDim` not `matrix.withDim`.

Comment: [ ] operator for a class? You better called it operator for an instance, as there is also a way to do matrix[i][j], where matrix is the class itself, not an instance of matrix class.

Comment: @warvariuc just modified title, thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

operator[] calls `__getitem__`:

```
class A:
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return index+1

a = A()
print(a[1]) # prints 2
```

You can implement [][] by returning a proxy object which represents the row and also responds to `__getitem__`. Or, you can accept tuple as index and use `A[i,j]` syntax.